# Cannot display interstitial ad on splash screen

Tags: android, flutter, admob, facebook-audience-network

I want to show interstitial ads on my app's splash screen.
But my admob gets error 3 with low fill rate
I tried facebook audience network but my placement get blocked due to policy violation
Is there any alternative or way to show fb ads on splash screen?

Comment: I don't think any network has better fill rate than admob.

Comment: Then why I am getting 4% of match rate on admob and 85% fill rate for fb audience ads

Comment: Which ad unit are you using?

Comment: many others, including me, are encountering the onadfailedtoload 3 error in admob, usually for a few days(some wait for a few weeks), then the fill rate will rise up to more than 80% (for my own case), without any code changes.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad I m using interstitial unit

Comment: @psycho11, I never got less than 99.5% fill rate for my any app, Admob is just brilliant for Interstitial and Banners. Not sure why you aren't getting that. Maybe you can take into consideration what Kenneth said.